# Mandrill- Attachments not sending attachment

Tags: mandrill

I am attempting to send a small rtf attachment through Mandrill. I have created the following json and tried it using the API test page. The attachment is base 64 encoded. The API reports no error and the email comes through but with no attachment. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
    "attachments": [
    {
        "type": "application/rtf",
        "name": "test.rtf",
        "content": "e1xydGYxXGFuc2lcYW5zaWNwZzEyNTJcZGVmZjBcZGVmbGFuZzIwNTd7XGZvbnR0Ymx7XGYwXGZuaWxcZmNoYXJzZXQwIENhbGlicmk7fX0NCntcKlxnZW5lcmF0b3IgTXNmdGVkaXQgNS40MS4yMS4yNTEwO31cdmlld2tpbmQ0XHVjMVxwYXJkXHNhMjAwXHNsMjc2XHNsbXVsdDFcbGFuZzlcZjBcZnMyMiB0aGlzIGlzIGEgdGVzdCBzZW5kaW5nIGZpbGVccGFyDQp9DQoA"
    }
],
"message": {
    "html": "<html>\r\n<body>test data</body>\r\n</html>\r\n",
    "subject": "Cloud Demo",
    "from_email": "jklovanc@hotmail.com",
    "preserve_recipients": true,
    "text": "",
    "to": [
        {
            "type": "to",
            "name": "",
            "email": "jklovanc@hotmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "from_name": "",
    "headers": {
        "reply-to": "jklovanc@hotmail.com"
    }
},
"key": #mykey#,
"async": false
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Attachments are part of the message object, so the attachments parameter should be nested under the message instead of at the same level. It should look like this instead:

```
{
    "message": {
        "attachments": [
            {
                "type": "application/rtf",
                "name": "test.rtf",
                "content": "e1xydGYxXGFuc2lcYW5zaWNwZzEyNTJcZGVmZjBcZGVmbGFuZzIwNTd7XGZvbnR0Ymx7XGYwXGZuaWxcZmNoYXJzZXQwIENhbGlicmk7fX0NCntcKlxnZW5lcmF0b3IgTXNmdGVkaXQgNS40MS4yMS4yNTEwO31cdmlld2tpbmQ0XHVjMVxwYXJkXHNhMjAwXHNsMjc2XHNsbXVsdDFcbGFuZzlcZjBcZnMyMiB0aGlzIGlzIGEgdGVzdCBzZW5kaW5nIGZpbGVccGFyDQp9DQoA"
            }
        ],
        "html": "<html>\r\n<body>test data</body>\r\n</html>\r\n",

....
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. It would be nice if Mandrill sent back and error rather than just ignoring it.

Comment: We can definitely look in to more validation, but it's generally not actually an error - it's an unknown parameter, which we'll ignore. For parameters that we actually support, we'll do at least minimal validation when you're not asyncing the call.

Comment: Sorry but putting a parameter in the wrong place in the json is an error as it does not produce the desired effect. To me, every time the system does something abnormal, like ignoring a parameter, it should be reported.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
//It works for me! good luck

/*LIBS*/
include 'lib/mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill.php';
$mandrill = new Mandrill('YOUR API KEY HERE');

/*ADMIN AND USER EMAIL*/
$admin_email = 'your_email@your_domain.com';
$client_email = 'the_email_of_the_client@mail.com';

/*attach PDF with base64_encode */
$attachment = file_get_contents('the_route_to_your_pdf'); // https://yourdomain/pdf_folder/mypdf.pdf
$attachment_encoded = base64_encode($attachment);

try{
    $user_message = array(
        'subject' => 'Your subject',
        'from_email' => $admin_email,
        'from_name' => 'my_domain_for_example',
        'html' =>  '<p>HTML template</p>',
        'to' => array(array('email' => $client_email, 'name' => 'Recipient 1')),
        'merge_vars' => array(array(
            'rcpt' => 'recipient1@domain.com',
            'vars' =>
            array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'FIRSTNAME',
                    'content' => 'Recipient 1 first name'),
                array(
                    'name' => 'LASTNAME',
                    'content' => 'Last name')
            ))),
        'attachments' => array(
            array(
                'content' => $attachment_encoded,
                'type' => "application/pdf",
                'name' => 'the_name_of_the_attach.pdf',
            ))
    );

    $res_user_mandrill = $mandrill->messages->send($user_message, $async=false, $ip_pool=null, $send_at=null);

} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {

}

?>
```

Comment: Could be useful if you point out places, in which your solution is different. Note that question was not PHP-related, so I wouldn't assume that as a solution technology.